# How to take the union of element in a nested list in R

Tags: r

I have a nested list in say `lst`(all the elements are of class `int`). I don't know the length of `lst` in advance; however I do know that each element of `lst` is a list of length say `k`

```
length(lst[[i]]) # this equals k and is known in advance, 
                 # this is true for i = 1 ... length(lst)
```

How do I take the `union` of the 1st element, 2nd element, ..., kth element of all the elements of `lst`

Specifically, if the length of `lst` is `n`, I want (not R code):

```
# I know that union can only be taken for 2 elements, 
# following is for illustration purposes
listUnion1 <- union(lst[[1, 1]], lst[[2, 1]], ..., lst[[n, 1]])
listUnion2 <- union(lst[[1, 2]], lst[[2, 2]], ..., lst[[n, 2]])
.
.
.
listUnionk <- union(lst[[1, k]], lst[[2, k]], ..., lst[[n, k]])
```

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here is a dataset that can be used, n = 3 and k = 2

```
list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:11), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
    structure(list(a = 6:11, b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
    structure(list(a = 12, b = 12), .Names = c("a", "b")))
```

Comment: Please let me know if the question is unclear or there is some problem. Please accept my sincere apologies in advance.

Comment: only thing that I found confusing is your notation `lst[[1, 1]]` which isn't correct R code for the list you show. I know you say it isn't R code, but `lst[[1]][1]` would have been better as it is R code. The other thing that would have been useful would have been some example output for the example data you provide (thanks for that by the way!). Apart from that I think the Q is good an interesting.

Comment: @gavin Thank you for your solution. I am sorry I should have been careful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a general solution, similar in spirit to that of @Ramnath, but avoiding the use of `union()` which is a binary function. The trick is to note that `union()` is implemented as:

```
unique(c(as.vector(x), as.vector(y)))
```

and the bit inside `unique()` can be achieved by unlisting the `n`th component of each list.

The full solution then is:

```
unionFun <- function(n, obj) {
    unique(unlist(lapply(obj, `[[`, n)))
}
lapply(seq_along(lst[[1]]), FUN = unionFun, obj = lst)
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[2]]
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5 12
```

on the data you showed.

A couple of useful features of this are:

- we use `` `[[` `` to subset `obj` in `unionFun`. This is similar to `function(x) x$a` in @Ramnath's Answer. However, we don't need an anonymous function (we use `` `[[` `` instead). The equivalent to @Ramnath's Answer is: `` lapply(lst, `[[`, 1) ``
- to generalise the above, we replace the `1` above with `n` in `unionFun()`, and allow our list to be passed in as argument `obj`.

Now that we have a function that will provide the union of the `n`th elements of a given list, we can `lapply()` over the indices `k`, applying our `unionFun()` to each sub-element of `lst`, using the fact that the length of `lst[[1]]` is the same as `length(lst[[k]])` for all `k`.

If it helps to have the names of the `n`th elements in the returned object, we can do:

```
> unions <- lapply(seq_along(lst[[1]]), FUN = unionFun, obj = lst)
> names(unions) <- names(lst[[1]])
> unions
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

$b
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5 12
```

Comment: Awesome -- Very very helpful! It is great to have people like you who take time to explain their solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution

```
# generate dummy data
x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T)
x2 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T)
df = data.frame(x1, x2, stringsAsFactors = F)

# find unique elements in each column
union_df = apply(df, 2, unique)
```

Let me know if this works

EDIT: Here is a solution for lists using the data you provided

```
mylist = list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:11), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
              structure(list(a = 6:11, b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
              structure(list(a = 12, b = 12), .Names = c("a", "b")))
list_a = lapply(mylist, function(x) x$a)
list_b = lapply(mylist, function(x) x$b)

union_a = Reduce(union, list_a)
union_b = Reduce(union, list_b)
```

If you have more than 2 elements in your list, we could generalize this code.

Comment: thanks, I would be very interested in a solution which uses *apply functions except apply (as it is just like using a for loop). Also df doesn't seem to be a list of lists?

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I am will accept Gavin's solution as it generalizes your idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way: Use `do.call/rbind` to line up the lists by "name" into a data-frame, then `apply` `unique/do.call` to each column of this data-frame. ( I modified your data slightly so the 'a' and 'b' unions are of different lengths, to make sure it works correctly).

```
lst <- list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:11), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
    structure(list(a = 6:10, b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
    structure(list(a = 12, b = 12), .Names = c("a", "b")))

> apply(do.call(rbind, lst),2, function( x ) unique( do.call( c, x)))
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12

$b
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5 12
```

Comment: That's a nice solution @Prasad. The `do.call` bit returns an interesting object.

Comment: @Gavin, thanks... yes the first do.call returns a strange-looking data-frame whose elements are lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your data

```
df <- list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:11), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
           structure(list(a = 6:11, b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
           structure(list(a = 12, b = 12), .Names = c("a", "b")))
```

This gives you the unique values of the nested lists:

```
library(plyr)
df.l <- llply(df, function(x) unlist(unique(x)))

R> df.l
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

[[2]]
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5

[[3]]
[1] 12
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Ramnath I changed the code a bit and hope this answer fits the needs of your question. For illustration I keep the previous answer as well. The slightly changed data has now an additional list.

```
df <- list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:11), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
           structure(list(a = 6:11, b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
           structure(list(a = 12, b = 12, c = 10:14), .Names = c("a", "b", "c")))


f.x <- function(x.list) {
  x.names <- names(x.list)
  i <- combn(x.names, 2)
  l <- apply(i, 2, function(y) x.list[y])
  llply(l, unlist)
}
```

Now you can apply the function to your data.

```
all.l <- llply(df, f.x)
llply(all.l, function(x) llply(x, unique))

R> [[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 12

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 12 10 11 13 14

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 12 10 11 13 14
```

However, the nested structure is not very user friendly. That could be changed a bit...

Comment: i think the OP wants the union of the kth elements of all the lists. your solution returns the union of all elements in each list. you might want to modify your plyr call

Comment: @Ramnath Thanks Ramnath, I changed it a bit. And left some room for more improvements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation "unlist" is a recursive function, hence regardless of the nesting level of the lists supplied you can get all elements by passing them to unlist. You can get the union of the sublists as follows.

```
lst <- list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:11), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
structure(list(a = 6:11, b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b")), 
structure(list(a = 12, b = 12), .Names = c("a", "b")))

lapply(lst, function(sublst) unique(unlist(sublst)))

[[1]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5

[[3]]
[1] 12
```